# How to achieve the latest date order with format MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#CommaDate') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CommaDate

CREATE TABLE #CommaDate
(
    DateFormate DATE
)

INSERT INTO #CommaDate VALUES('2018-02-24'),('2018-01-10'),('2017-05-23'),('2017-04-06')

SELECT DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DateFormate,101) 
              FROM #CommaDate 
              ORDER BY ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DateFormate,101) DESC 
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1, '')
FROM #CommaDate
```

What i expected is with latest order date with formate MM/DD/YYY

```
02/24/2018,01/10/2018,05/23/2017,04/06/2017
```

Comment: Do you *need* the `DISTINCT` in your subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried like this

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#CommaDate') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #CommaDate

    CREATE TABLE #CommaDate
    (
        DateFormate DATE
    )

    INSERT INTO #CommaDate VALUES('2018-02-24'),('2018-01-10'),('2017-05-23'),('2017-04-06')

    SELECT DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT  ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DateFormate,101) 
                  FROM #CommaDate 
                  ORDER BY concat(',' , year(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DateFormate,101))) desc  
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1, '')
    FROM #CommaDate
```

or

```
SELECT  distinct STUFF((SELECT  ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DateFormate,101) 
              FROM #CommaDate 
             -- ORDER BY concat(',' , year(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DateFormate,101))) desc  
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1, '')
FROM #CommaDate
```

output

```
02/24/2018,01/10/2018,05/23/2017,04/06/2017
```

Comment: your queries show wrong order with this input... `('2018-02-25')`

Answer (score 2):

Since the datatype is `DATE` you can easily group and order the result inside the sub query. Apparently you're expecting a 1row x 1col result so you can ditch the outer `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DateFormate, 101)
    FROM #CommaDate
    GROUP BY DateFormate
    ORDER BY DateFormate DESC
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')
```

Output:

```
(No column name)
02/24/2018,01/10/2018,05/23/2017,04/06/2017
```

Comment: That depends on whether the inner `DISTINCT` was a required part of the real query or not. It is the right general approach though.

Answer (score 2):

Remove **`DISTINCT`**, and add **`ORDER BY DateFormate DESC`** in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Just separate `ORDER BY` and `DISTINCT` and use Date values to sort

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#CommaDate') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CommaDate

CREATE TABLE #CommaDate
(
    DateFormate DATE
)

INSERT INTO #CommaDate VALUES('2018-02-24'),('2018-01-10'),('2017-05-23'),('2017-04-06')

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),d.DateFormate,101) 
              FROM ( 
                SELECT DISTINCT DateFormate 
                FROM #CommaDate
              ) d
              ORDER BY d.DateFormate DESC 
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1, '')
FROM #CommaDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope It will work

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#CommaDate') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #CommaDate

    CREATE TABLE #CommaDate
    (
        DateFormate DATE
    )

    INSERT INTO #CommaDate VALUES ('2018-02-24'),('2018-01-10'),('2017-05-23'),('2017-04-06')



         SELECT DISTINCT STUFF(
            (
            select  ', ' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),convert(datetime,DateFormate,101),101)  from #CommaDate order by  DateFormate desc
                          FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1,1, '')
            FROM #CommaDate
```

Output

```
 02/24/2018, 01/10/2018, 05/23/2017, 04/06/2017
```